# How to create a pricelist of Products, that are formed from multiple "MicroProducts"?

Tags: ms-access

I have a table called [MicroProducts] with 3 products: Micro1, Micro2, Micro3.

Those products are parts of a bigger product or somethimes products on their own. So I need a table [RealProducts] where I would like to have "real products": Product1 = Micro1 + Micro3, Product2 = Micro1, Product3 = Micro1 + Micro2.

Every MicroProduct has its own price (for simplicity, Micro1 = $1, Micro2 = $2, etc). In table RealProducts I would need to see combined prices, since that table would actually be my real PriceList. Then there would be a Form, where you add new RealProducts (you assemble them from the MicroProducts. I am struggling with how to do all that?

Comment: Search for _bill of materials_.

Answer (score 0):

I did a working example here https://github.com/tst32/compositedPriceExample-msaccess

When autoexec macros open Form `frmRealProducts` query for create table with RealProduct prices is executed

```
SELECT RealProductsNames.ID, 
First(RealProductsNames.RealProductName) AS FirstOfRealProductName, 
First(Format(DSum("[MicroProductPrice]","[MicroProducts]"," 
[RealProductID] =" & [RealProductsNames]![ID] & ""),"$0.00")) AS 
TotalPrice INTO RealProductPrices
FROM RealProductsNames INNER JOIN MicroProducts ON 
RealProductsNames.ID = MicroProducts.RealProductID
GROUP BY RealProductsNames.ID;
```

Also you can see  a report button - Pricelist for each composited article and sub-articles prices

this is the main trick - to create a new table by query based on table with micropoduct prices and a table with RealProduct names
[realtion schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idUgY.png)

<strike>I advise you to use one of the available templates to create a new access database, for example, take the "Time and billing" template. Look at how it works.
there are records in in project extended table, then a calculated field

`Outstanding: [Total Billables]+[Total Expenses]-[Total Payments]`

[Total Expenses]  takes values from another table named expenses.</strike>

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iw7aw.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzcZf.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lkfid.png)

Comment: You need to more clearly articulate the need for a (self-join) many micro products to many microproducts or in other words an assemblies table.  Then elaborate on why you might continue to a Bill of Materials design where if one product may have many different assemblies you keep the product outside the assemblies table and form a super many to many relationship (ProductsAssemblies).

Comment: You are right, instead of advising you to read google and microsoft in general terms, it is better to give a working example. so i did (provide link to github with solution)